# __RefactorLog table in SQL Server - safe to drop it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

SSDT (I suspect) creates a table called __RefactorLog in any database you point it towards.

If I've hit a release is there any harm in deleting this table as I don't see any benefit in including it in schema creation scripts at the time of deployment?

I can't see any downside to it myself, but I'd like to pose the question to the knowledgeable people here to see if there's something I'm missing...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is created by SSDT when you use a refactor in SSDT (like Refactor -> Rename) if you do a deployment and just clear out the table it will retry to do any old refactorings which could just fail or cause a disaster!

If you clear the table make sure you also remove the entries from the refactorlog.xml in your project - the file is pretty obvious.

Make sure you don't try to deploy an old dacpac (I guess this is unlikely anyway)

Ed

Comment: Ed's response is accurate. I'd just like to note that the most common "refactor" operation in an SSDT project is using the table designer to rename a column in a table. Editing the column name in the T-SQL panel is not considered a refactor operation, but editing the column name in the table designer is considered a refactor. This is a subtle, but important behavior to note.

Comment: You can initiate a rename from SQL text edtitor: 1) from the designer T-SQL pane use Shift-F10 or right-click, "Refactor / Rename... ", 2) from view or SPROC use Ctrl+., just like in any other VS or VSCode editor to initiate cleanup or refactor. (response to @StevenGreen)  He's correct that "normal edits" are not analyzed for possible renames.